# how to check if currency is different in method transferMoney(User fromUser, User toUser, int amount)?

Tags: java

```
@Override
public void withdraw(User user, int amount) {

    if (!checkWithdraw(user,amount))
        return;
    user.setBalance(user.getBalance() - amount - amount*user.getBank().getCommission(amount));
}

@Override
public void fund(User user, int amount) {
    if (!checkFund(user, amount))
        return;
    user.setBalance(user.getBalance() + amount);
}

@Override
public void transferMoney(User fromUser, User toUser, int amount) {
    if (!checkWithdraw(fromUser,amount))
        return;

    if (!checkFund(toUser, amount))
        return;
    fromUser.setBalance(fromUser.getBalance()-amount-amount*fromUser.getBank().getCommission(amount));
    toUser.setBalance(toUser.getBalance()+amount);
    **if (fromUser.getBank().getCurrency()==toUser.getBank().getCurrency()) return;**
}
```

i need to check if currency is different between users and if it is, i need to return null.
I think its incorrect, help me to find out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know if the transfert has been done, I'd suggest to return a boolean value, and so check the currency and return `false` if different. Also use the methods you write to transfert money can be a good idea

```
@Override
public boolean transferMoney(User fromUser, User toUser, int amount) {
    if (!checkWithdraw(fromUser, amount)) return false;
    if (!checkFund(toUser, amount)) return false;
    if (fromUser.getBank().getCurrency() != toUser.getBank().getCurrency()) return false;

    withdraw(fromUser, amount);
    fund(toUser, amount);
    return true;
}
```

But, as the methods `withdraw` and `fund` also do the check, there is redundant code that is called, you could do like :

```
@Override
public boolean withdraw(User user, int amount) {
    if (!checkWithdraw(user, amount)) return false;
    user.setBalance(user.getBalance() - amount - amount * user.getBank().getCommission(amount));
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean fund(User user, int amount) {
    if (!checkFund(user, amount)) return false;
    user.setBalance(user.getBalance() + amount);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean transferMoney(User fromUser, User toUser, int amount) {
    if (fromUser.getBank().getCurrency() != toUser.getBank().getCurrency()) return false;
    return withdraw(fromUser, amount) && fund(toUser, amount);
}
```

Explanation:

- you're going to call `withdraw`

  - if it works it'll return `true` and the second part of the logical expression will be tested and so executed
  - if it doesn't work (`checkWithdraw` not ok) it'll return `false` and the second part of the logical expression will not ne executed, and you won't `fund` the other account
- if `withdraw` returns `true` it'll call the `fund` method and the global will return

  - `fund` return true : `true && true` so return `true`
  - `fund` return false: `true && false` so return `false`